# How to fire events correctly from C++(ActiveX) to JavaScript

Tags: javascript, event-handling, dom-events, activex, atl

I followed Microsoft's tutorial on how to implement connection points and supposedly trigger functions from C++. The problem is I can't get `IConnectionPointImpl::m_vec` array to be initialized with proper connections, hence, `m_vec.size = 0`.

In my .IDL file, I declared the following interface:

```
[
    uuid(F5219084-9D70-474A-8C05-46FFD1FCCC71),
    version(1.0),
    helpstring("BCPlayer 1.0 Type Library")
]
library VPlayerLib
{
    importlib("stdole2.tlb");
    [
        uuid(C4DFAB9A-435A-41A9-96B6-B23056DAA3FC),
        helpstring("_IVPlayerEvents Interface")
    ]
    dispinterface _IVPlayerEvents
    {
    properties:
    methods:
        [id(1)] HRESULT OnInfoCallback([in] BSTR pPlayerName, [in] BOOL bSuccessMsg, [in] LONG nCode, [in] HRESULT hrRet);
    };
...
...
```

Later on, using Visual Studio's Connection Point wizard, created the following proxy:

```
template<class T>
class CProxy_IVPlayerEvents :
    public ATL::IConnectionPointImpl<T, &__uuidof(_IVPlayerEvents)>
{
public:
    HRESULT Fire_OnInfoCallback(BSTR pPlayerName, BOOL bSuccessMsg, LONG nCode, HRESULT hrRet)
    {
        HRESULT hr = S_OK;
        T * pThis = static_cast<T *>(this);
        int cConnections = m_vec.GetSize();

        for (int iConnection = 0; iConnection < cConnections; iConnection++)
        {
            pThis->Lock();
            CComPtr<IUnknown> punkConnection = m_vec.GetAt(iConnection);
            pThis->Unlock();

            IDispatch * pConnection = static_cast<IDispatch *>(punkConnection.p);

            if (pConnection)
            {
                CComVariant avarParams[4];
                avarParams[3] = pPlayerName;
                avarParams[3].vt = VT_BSTR;
                avarParams[2] = bSuccessMsg;
                avarParams[2].vt = VT_BOOL;
                avarParams[1] = nCode;
                avarParams[1].vt = VT_I4;
                avarParams[0] = hrRet;
                avarParams[0].vt = VT_HRESULT;
                CComVariant varResult;

                DISPPARAMS params = { avarParams, NULL, 4, 0 };
                hr = pConnection->Invoke(1, IID_NULL, LOCALE_USER_DEFAULT, DISPATCH_METHOD, &params, &varResult, NULL, NULL);
            }
        }
        return hr;
    }
};
```

in my ATL object added the following inheritances:

```
, public IConnectionPointContainerImpl<VPlayer>
, public CProxy_IVPlayerEvents<VPlayer>
, public IProvideClassInfo2Impl<&__uuidof(VPlayer), &__uuidof(_IVPlayerEvents), &LIBID_VPlayerLib>
```

mapping:

```
    COM_INTERFACE_ENTRY(IConnectionPointContainer)
    COM_INTERFACE_ENTRY(IProvideClassInfo)
    COM_INTERFACE_ENTRY(IProvideClassInfo2)
END_COM_MAP()
```

connection point map:

```
BEGIN_CONNECTION_POINT_MAP(VPlayer)
    CONNECTION_POINT_ENTRY(__uuidof(_IVPlayerEvents))
END_CONNECTION_POINT_MAP()
```

In Javascript, I tried binding with `attachEvent`, and `addEventListener`, whereas the first one added 4 connections to `m_vec`, but caused a memory corruption during the destruction process of `CComvaraint`:

```
avarParams[3] = pPlayerName;
avarParams[3].vt = VT_BSTR;
```

and `addEventListener` didn't change `::m_vec` and kept it zero sized. After reviewing MSDN, I realized that `addEventListener` is the preferred method of binding callbacks from IE9 and above

JavaScript code for events binding:

```
function OnInfoCallback(){
    var a = arguments[0];
    var b = arguments[1];
    var c = arguments[2];
    var d = arguments[3];
    alert("here");
}
...
...

player.addEventListener("OnInfoCallback", OnInfoCallback, false);
```

Comment: Did you figure out a way to make this work?

Comment: Actually i did, i didn't use any connection points, simply created a setter function that receives IDispatch* and stores it into a CComPtr<IDispatch>, later on invoked the callback using InvokeN().

Answer (score 0):

From the OP's comment:

> Actually I made this work by as I didn't use any connection points, simply created a setter function that receives `IDispatch*` and stores it into a `CComPtr<IDispatch>`, later on invoked the callback using `InvokeN()`.